# Exporting my web scrape results from Python

Tags: python, csv

This might be very simple, but I am very new to python and I simply can't even figure out where to start.

So I have written a code that successfully scrapes the data I want from a webpage. Now my problem is I have no idea of how to export it to csv, this is how my code looks.

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for numb in range(1, 3):
    urls= "http://www.blocket.se/bostad/uthyres?cg_multi=3020&cg_multi=3100&cg_multi=3120&cg_multi=3060&cg_multi=3070&sort=&ss=&se=&ros=&roe=&bs=&be=&mre=&q=&q=&q=&save_search=1&l=0&md=th&o=" +str(numb) +"&f=p&f=c&f=b&ca=11&w=3"
    r = requests.get(urls)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    data = soup.find_all("div", {"itemtype": "http://schema.org/Offer"})

    for item in data:
        try:
            print item.contents[3].find_all("span", {"class": "subject-param category"})[0].text
        except:
            pass
        try:
            print item.contents[3].find_all("span", {"class": "subject-param address separator"})[0].text
        except:
            pass
        try:
            print item.contents[3].find_all("span", {"class": "li_detail_params first rooms"})[0].text
        except:
            pass
        try:
            print item.contents[3].find_all("span", {"class": "li_detail_params monthly_rent"})[0].text
        except:
            pass
        try:
            print item.contents[3].find_all("span", {"class": "li_detail_params size"})[0].text  
        except:
            pass
        try:
            print item.contents[3].find_all("span", {"class": "li_detail_params first weekly_rent_offseason"})[0].text
        except:
            pass
```

And it prints this:

```
lägenhet

                Stockholms stad - Bromma

1 rum
4 000 kr/mån

            villa

                Linköping

100 m²

            lägenhet

                Stockholms stad - Maria, Gamla Stan, Högalid

1 rum
8 000 kr/mån
36 m²

            lägenhet

                Stockholms stad - Hägersten, Liljeholmen

1 rum
7 500 kr/mån
26 m²
```

Sure its not the nicest output but I don't really care about that. Now, could someone point me towards how I would be able to export this to csv? As I said, I don't even know where to get started.

Comment: don't catch every exception, `except:pass` is never a good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the print statements, add your information to a list. Finally use csv.writer to spit it out to the console:

```
import unicodecsv as csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import StringIO



for numb in range(1, 3):


    urls= "http://www.blocket.se/bostad/uthyres?cg_multi=3020&cg_multi=3100&cg_multi=3120&cg_multi=3060&cg_multi=3070&sort=&ss=&se=&ros=&roe=&bs=&be=&mre=&q=&q=&q=&save_search=1&l=0&md=th&o=" +str(numb) +"&f=p&f=c&f=b&ca=11&w=3"



    r = requests.get(urls)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')



    data = soup.find_all("div", {"itemtype": "http://schema.org/Offer"})

    data_list = []
    for item in data:
        data_item = {}
        try:
            data_item['category'] = item.contents[3].find_all("span", {"class": "subject-param category"})[0].text
        except:
            pass
        try:
            data_item['address separator'] =  item.contents[3].find_all("span", {"class": "subject-param address separator"})[0].text
        except:
            pass
        try:
            data_item['first rooms'] = item.contents[3].find_all("span", {"class": "li_detail_params first rooms"})[0].text
        except:
            pass
        try:
            data_item['monthly_rent'] = item.contents[3].find_all("span", {"class": "li_detail_params monthly_rent"})[0].text
        except:
            pass
        try:
            data_item['size'] = item.contents[3].find_all("span", {"class": "li_detail_params size"})[0].text
        except:
            pass
        try:
            data_item['weekly_rent_offseason'] = item.contents[3].find_all("span", {"class": "li_detail_params first weekly_rent_offseason"})[0].text
        except:
            pass
        data_list.append(data_item)
    out = StringIO.StringIO()
    csv_writer = csv.writer(out)
    [csv_writer.writerow(data.values()) for data in data_list]
    print out.getvalue()
```

you'll need to install the following libraries in addition to the base system:

1. unicodecsv -- for the non-ascii characters to be written
2. beautifulsoup4 -- for HTML parsing
3. requests -- for HTTP access

This does spit out CSV for me, If it doesn't for you, let me know.

Comment: Thank you! I suspected I had to save the data in some way, when I tried it before I only managed to save one item, the last one, for some reason. I do have a slight problem with your code though, it gives me an error message looking like: 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/fredrikkopsch/Documents/PythonPrograms/scapingblocket.py", line 83, in <module>
    csv_writer.writerows(data_list)
Error: sequence expected`

Any suggestions to what might be wrong? Will this code, when it works for me, print the data in rows for each variable? Thanks again, @hd1

Comment: You're most welcome.. I just fixed the script and added further information on the dependencies.

Comment: Thanks! Now it worked without errors. Just one more question, how do I print this to a csv file that I can read in, say excel? @hd1